# Condition A>B>C not getting the right output

Tags: verilog

I made a program that is able to compare 3 inputs for them to get the largest value (F)
The problem is I cannot get the expected output of the problem.
Expectation:

```
A      B      C      F
001(1) 111(9) 100(4) 111(9)
001(1) 001(1)  001(1) 000
```

Actual Output:

[image: My Output]

```
module InputComparator(A,B,C,F);
input [2:0]A;
input [2:0]B;
input [2:0]C;
output reg [2:0]F;

    always @* begin
        if (A>B>C) begin   
            F = A;
            end
        else if (A>B<C) begin 
            F = B;
            end
        else if (A<B<C) begin 
            F = C;
            end
        else begin
            F = 3'b000; 
        end
end
endmodule

module testbench;
reg [2:0] A;
reg [2:0] B; 
reg [2:0] C; 

wire [2:0]F; 


InputComparator test(A,B,C,F);


initial
begin


$display("--------------------------------------------------------");
$display("3 Input Comparator");
$display("--------------------------------------------------------");
$display("Time\tA\tB\tC\tF");
$display("--------------------------------------------------------");
$monitor("%g\t%b\t%b\t%b\t%b",$time,A,B,C,F);


    A=3'b000; B=3'b000; C=3'b000;
#1  A=3'b101; B=3'b101; C=3'b101;
#1  A=3'b001; B=3'b111; C=3'b100;
#1  A=3'b110; B=3'b001; C=3'b101;
#1  A=3'b001; B=3'b100; C=3'b101;
#1$display("--------------------------------------------------------");

#1$display("--------------------------------------------------------");
#9 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to chain comparison operators like that: `A>B>C`.  That does not do what you think it does, and it is a common pitfall (see explanation below).  You must separate each comparison:

```
module InputComparator(A,B,C,F);
input [2:0]A;
input [2:0]B;
input [2:0]C;
output reg [2:0]F;

    always @* begin
        if ((A>B) && (A>C)) begin   
            F = A;
            end
        else if ((B>A) && (B>C)) begin 
            F = B;
            end
        else if ((C>A) && (C>B)) begin 
            F = C;
            end
        else begin
            F = 3'b000; 
        end
end
endmodule
```

I get this correct output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
3 Input Comparator
--------------------------------------------------------
Time    A   B   C   F
--------------------------------------------------------
0   000 000 000 000
1   101 101 101 000
2   001 111 100 111
3   110 001 101 110
4   001 100 101 101
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Verilog interprets `(A>B>C)` as `( (A>B) > C )`.  It evaluates `(A>B)` first, which resolves to either 0 or 1.  Let's assume it resolves to 1.  Thus, we are left with `(1 > C)`, which is clearly not what you intended.